# Ordering a list of objects in the same order as another list of objects with objects having some common attribute

Tags: sorting, java-8, comparator

I have two ArrayLists like below;

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> mapList;
List<myclass> sortedDtos;
```

As the name implies `sortedDtos` is already sorted.

```
`myclass` has a field called `jobNo`
The HashMap has a key called `jobNo`
```

Basically I want to order `mapList` based on `sortedDtos` by comparing the attribute `jobNo`.

How can I do this in Java 8?

This seems to work correctly, also can be probably be made more efficient.

```
 List<String> jobNos = new ArrayList();
            sortedDtos.stream().forEach(dto -> jobNos.add(dto.getJobNo()));

            // sort maplist based on the sorting of the dtos
            mapList.sort(Comparator.comparing(el -> jobNos.indexOf(el.get("jobNo"))));
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input & expected output. It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: *This seems to work correctly, also can be probably be made more efficient*...https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network 
 - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest the following way. This approach involves providing your own custom comparator to sort the map.

```
    Collections.sort(mapList, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        List<String> list = sortedDtos.stream().map(l -> l.jobNo).collect(Collectors.toList());
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> map1, HashMap<String, String> map2) {
            if(list.indexOf(map1.get("jobNo")) < list.indexOf(map2.get("jobNo"))) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if(list.indexOf(map1.get("jobNo")) > list.indexOf(map2.get("jobNo"))) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
```